# Remote Event Logs Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, event-viewer

I have the following requirement

- Read a remote machines event logs
- Pass over credentials
- Allow a user to page through this in an MVC Application

From my research I believe this can be achieved using the [EventLogSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogsession%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) combined with the [EventLogQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) & [EventLogReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Whilst I've managed to successfully conenct to a remote machine with credentials and read the log files I'm stuck with the paging aspect. I don't know how to do the equivalent of LINQ's Skip & Take methods with the EventLogQuery.

Some of these machines will have > 20 000 logs and I'd like to avoid loading them all into memory before paging.

Is there a way I can achieve paging with the EventLogQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea of how to approach this using the lazy evaluation capabilities of `yield return`. Given a query to execute using `EventLogQuery`, you can do as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<EventRecord> QueryEventRecords(string queryString)
{
    var query = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, queryString);
    using (var reader = new EventLogReader(query))
    {
        EventRecord eventRecord;
        while ((eventRecord = reader.ReadEvent()) != null)
        {
            yield return eventRecord;
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can then execute the query and then use your favourite LINQ operators on the `IEnumerable`.

```
var result = QueryEventRecords("*[System[(Level = 3)]]")
    .Skip(10)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

That said, paging a remote PC isn't going to fly in an MVC application - retaining statefulness of the iterator between screen paging would not be advisable. What might better would be to pre-fetch all events in the query of interest from the remote machines and instead save these to a central database (i.e. similar to enterprise software like [SCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Operations_Manager)). You can then browse through the event data at your leisure using an ORM like EF.